# Homebrew Apache directories on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: apache, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I went thru any tutorial I could find to install and configure Apache on Big Sur. Invariably, the tutorial when discussing the config files will point to /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf that needs to be massaged a bit. The only trouble is that the file doesn't exist when I check that dir. Any idea? Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: I did an uninstall and install of httpd per requested and I still don't get the /usr/local/. There must be something different the homebrew configuration.

> ```
> ➜  ~ brew uninstall httpd          
> Uninstalling /opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.49... (1,660 files, 31.9MB)
> ➜  ~ brew install httpd            
> ==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/httpd/manifests/2.4.49
> Already downloaded: /Users/johnny/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6c60d66c3915be5c993e144a743960b9e6be26e557efeeb6c61f530c79ffed34--httpd-2.4.49.bottle_manifest.json
> ==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/httpd/blobs/sha256:e6ebcb4a1307
> Already downloaded: /Users/johnny/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8506f199d5d7def536481d6fa87aa94c25201b57072d032e97edb8ce78fa86a3--httpd--2.4.49.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
> ==> Pouring httpd--2.4.49.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
> ==> Caveats
> DocumentRoot is /opt/homebrew/var/www.
>
> The default ports have been set in /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf to 8080 and in
> /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf to 8443 so that httpd can run without sudo.
>
> To restart httpd after an upgrade:
>   brew services restart httpd
> Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
>   /opt/homebrew/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
> ==> Summary
>   /opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.49: 1,660 files, 31.9MB
> ➜  ~
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Stealing the comment that @JohnDifool made above, Brew moves the httpd.conf file now and then. I'm sure they have a good reason. The above was correct for OS X Big Sur, but things do change. I got here looking for the current location under Ventura 13.4, and other users will probably come across this page as well. However, the find function in the terminal is your friend here, like John pointed out.

```
find /opt -name httpd.conf


me@mymac ~ % find /opt -name httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.54_1/.bottle/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.54_1/.bottle/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
```

and the paths will appear.  At this time (7/28/23) under Mac OS X Ventura 13.4 the file httpd.conf is in /opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/

If the server is running you have an additional option. The http daemon can tell you. This is pretty handy if you have more than one httpd.conf file on your system, say one from brew and another from the Apple default file.

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Answer (score 2):

[Edited and updated]
I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.7 / Xcode-select version 2373 and by running `$ brew install httpd` I can install the Apache service under `/usr/local/`

Can you please remove and install it again by using the same command and sharing all the output?

These are the important things:

```
  DocumentRoot is /usr/local/var/www.

  The default ports have been set in /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf to 8080 and in
  /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf to 8443 so that httpd can run without sudo.

  To start httpd:
    brew services start httpd
  Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
    /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

This is the list of directories.

```
  $ ls -lrt /usr/local/etc/httpd
    total 200
    drwxr-xr-x  14 user  admin    448 Sep 22 23:35 extra
    -rw-r--r--   1 user  admin  21222 Sep 22 23:35 httpd.conf
    -rw-r--r--   1 user  admin  13064 Sep 22 23:35 magic
    -rw-r--r--   1 user  admin  60847 Sep 22 23:35 mime.types
    drwxr-xr-x   4 user  admin    128 Sep 22 23:35 original
```

And this is my test showing it is working.

```
  $ curl localhost:8080
    <html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>

  $ tail -f /usr/local//var/log/httpd/access_log
    ::1 - - [22/Sep/2021:23:39:35 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 45
```

Based on your output and the brew documentation I believe you are using `Apple Silicon` is that correct, can you confirm?

https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

- This script installs Homebrew to its preferred prefix (/usr/local for macOS Intel, /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon, and /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew for Linux) so that you don’t need sudo when you brew install. It is a careful script; it can be run even if you have stuff installed in the preferred prefix already. It tells you exactly what it will do before it does it too. You have to confirm everything it will do before it starts.

Comment: I did and that's the issue: brew reinstall httpd puts homebrew in /opt/homebrew/opt/httpd. In your tutorial linked, I fail at: tail -f /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log
tail: /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log: No such file or directory. The config files are in: > find /opt -name httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.49/.bottle/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.49/.bottle/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
So obviously /usr/local/etc doesn't point to /op/homebrew/etc.

Comment: I added the brew command output. Still no cigar.

Comment: It is clear now that your Homebrew installation is under /opt/homebrew/ not /usr/local, why don you try: `tail -f /opt/homebrew/var/log/httpd/access_log` the difference in the path is mentioned in the Homebrew documentation, you would like to fix that and move specifically to /usr/local just to follow exactly the tutorial or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want the config files to be in /usr/local. Instead homebrew is installing httpd in /opt/homebrew and the configs are under that dir too. I did remove everything and reinstall. Same deal. It's not like i am not trying...

Comment: Please check the Homebrew documentation and CONFIRM if you are running macOS Intel or Apple Silicon -> https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
This script installs Homebrew to its preferred prefix (/usr/local for macOS Intel, /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon and /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew for Linux) so that you don’t need sudo when you brew install.

Comment: Apple M1. Leaving on the edge... So I will deduct that all the tutorials out there are made on Intel chip without mentioning the M1 variations. Pity.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be your case.